# Jmeter Callable Statement INOUT BLOB

Tags: json, jdbc, jmeter, blob, inout

I have a problem executing a JDBC request, connecting via jdbc:oracle:thin:

as part of the request, a Blob type field is sent that contains a JSON inside, the main problem is that the BLOB must be parsed before executing the procedure, it does not allow the return BLOB field to be captured, since the field BLOB is IN/OUT, the stored procedure changes JSON values ​​and returns it.

[Data used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfgzO.png)

How can I capture the response blob?
And validate changes in JSON